# EntityFramework - Delete Many to Many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I have the following entity tree:

```
ParameterDefinition-->ParameterOperation
ParameterDefinition-->ParameterGroup-->Parameter
```

Also there is a many to many relationship (mapped to a FK-FK table) between `ParameterOperation` and `Parameter`.
All associations are declared as Delete cascade (only the many to many is not Delete cascade).
The thing is that when I `MarkAsDeleted` `Parameter` Object through `ParameterOperation` 
(`ParameterDefinition.ParameterOperations[0].Parameters[0].MarkAsDeleted`) it is deleted from DB and the map table is updated as well (row is deleted), but when I try to delete `Parameter` From `ParameterGroup` 
(`ParameterDefinition.ParameterGroups[0].Parameters[0].MarkAsDeleted`) it is not deleted at all (no delete query is executed on DB).
What might be the problem?

Also how do i delete a many to many relationship? for example I want to keep all Parameters and all `ParameterOperations` but I want to delete the relationship between `Parameters[0]` and `ParameterOperations[0]`.

How can I do it?

if I set the NavigationProperty - `ParameterDefinition.ParameterOperations[0].Parameters.MarkAsDeleted` it actually deleted the Parameter from DB what I don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply removing the `Parameter` Entity from the `ParameterOperation's` collection, and then saving your context should be enough to delete the many to many relationship that exists in the junction table.

```
ParameterDefinition.ParameterOperations[0].Parameters.Remove(ParameterDefinition.ParameterOperations[0].Parameters[0]);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: right, but it removes the parameter from the Parameters table as well. also when i try to remove the parameter from ParameterGroups it even doesn't execute the delete query on the DB. I look for the changed entities in the ChangeTracker and nothing is there

Comment: Are you wanting to actually delete the parameter, or remove the relationship?  Did you notice that I'm not actually deleting the Parameter (not using MarkAsDeleted) but only removing it from the many to many collection?  When you're wanting to delete the parameter from the ParameterGroup, can you post more code?  Where are you calling SaveChanges?  Is the ParameterGroup already attached to the context?

Comment: I am trying to remove only the relation- which is not removed this way. When i am trying to remove from ParameterGroup i just do it this way- ParameterDefinition.ParameterGroups[0].Parameters[0].MarkAsDeleted. how do i check if it is attached to the Context? I first load the ParameterDefinition with all it's navigations before deleting Parameter

Comment: any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Honestly not with the information we have.. everything should just work.  Can you post your entire method where you're getting the entities from your context, doing the update, and then saving the context?